# jquery element not resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there a reason why this jquery code does not work as expected?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" >
<script src="<c:url value="/jquery-1.11.3.js" />"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function selectRat(){
    alert('ajax 1'); //displays OK
    alert('ajax 2: ' +  document.getElementById('test').value );  //displays OK

    alert( $('#test').val() ); //does NOT display

    alert('end of function'); //never reached as previous line fails
    }



</script>

</head>

<body>


    <select  class="offset2 span4 form-control"  name="test"" id = "test" onchange="selectRat()">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
    </select>


</body>
</html>
```

I would like to understand why :

```
alert('ajax 2: ' +  document.getElementById('test').value );
```

displays fine,
but

```
alert( $('#test').val() );
```

does **not** display?

I am pretty sure the reason is obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: The jQuery library failed to load. Open the browser's error console, it would have told you that.

Comment: You aren't loading jQuery properly. Your `script` tag is malformed. It should be `<script src="path/to/jquery"></script>`

Comment: The problem is the way you're loading jQuery to your page: `<c:url value="/jquery-1.11.3.js" />`. Use the CDN and it will work. If you can't, change the `script src` to use single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, ensure that the jQuery library has loaded in correctly by checking your console log to see if any resources failed to load.

Second of all, your HTML select had a problem and had an extra `"` which could have been causing some problems.

Just to prove everything is working fine, I've cleaned up your example and instead of alerting the output, since it gets blocked from the code snippet viewer, and console logging it out.

```js
function selectRat() {
  console.log('ajax 1'); //displays OK
  console.log('ajax 2: ' + document.getElementById('test').value); //displays OK

  console.log($('#test').val()); //does NOT display

  console.log('end of function'); //never reached as previous line fails
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="offset2 span4 form-control" name="test" id="test" onchange="selectRat()">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No problem, jQuery can be a fickle thing but just double checking everything usually helps